# Message order in Meteor DDP

Tags: meteor, ddp

Suppose the client goes offline. During that time, the following code executes:

```
Messages.remove(oldMessage._id)
Messages.insert(newMessage)
```

When client goes online, is it guaranteed that `remove` will execute first, `insert` will execute second?

In other words, is it guaranteed that only one of those messages will be present in database at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove will execute first and then the insert. Meteor queue all the DDP messages and execute in order when it connected again.